# A simple explanation of CWM and Odin

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, odin

I'm going to root my Samsung Galaxy Note and I come across the terms CWM and Odin very often. What exactly are they? It seems that CWM is used for rooting and Odin for flashing the phone. Is there more to it?

I've posted here because I have been unable to to find a good explanation online.

Comment: For the second half of your question, see this previous question: [What is the Odin tool?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CWM is the shortform of [ClockWorkMod](http://www.clockworkmod.com/).  ROMManager, CWM recovery, Tether etc are their products.  CWM Recovery and ROMManager are tools which enables you to backup your current ROM, install custom ROMs etc.

If you are interested in knowing more about CWM, see [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-clockworkmod-recovery-and-how-to-use-it-on-android-complete-guide/) page.  For rooting you do not need CWM. In fact for installing CWM you need to be rooted.

For anyone who plays with ROMs, tweaking and testing, CWM Recovery or some thing equivalent to it is mandatory and would save your neck several times.

Also, you could specify which part you are not clear with.  It will help to get better answers. :)

Comment: I would give all my upboats if I could. I'm trying to figure this out as a I go along. So CWM Recovery replaces the default menu that i get when I press (Vol Up + Home + Power) ad adds more options to it, right? ..and in order to install CWM Recovery, I have to download ROM Manager from the Play market and use the "Flash" option which would replace my boot-up options. Thanks Narayan.

Comment: Yes, CWMRecovery replaces the standard recovery which is not that useful. As you had said, you have to download ROM Manager and choose "Flash CWMR". It will identify your device's code name and will opt you to choose if it has ambiguity.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla To flash CWM using ROM Manager, you need root access. If you aren't rooted, you can use Odin to flash CWM directly.