# Odin vs Clockworkmod

Tags: updates, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung, odin

I want to flash a new Stock Rom on my Galaxy Mega. I'm quite hesitant using Clorkworkmod. Will I lose my Root if I use Odin to upgrade? Also, what happens to Clockworkmod if I use Odin?

Comment: They are 2 completely different things, Clockworkmod is the recovery on your phone, Odin is a PC appliction. The only way you'll lose root and lose Clockworkmod is if you flash a STOCK firmware to unroot and restore your device OR you are flashing a new recovery. Otherwise they won't interfere with each other. [This question should cover the basics](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26860/a-simple-explanation-of-cwm-and-odin?rq=1) and also see [this one](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool?rq=1)

Comment: Can I use Clockworkmod to flash a stock rom? and will I lose my root if I do? Is there a performance gain if I use Odin to perform the Stock ROM flash instead of CWM and will I lose root?

Comment: You can't flash stock rom in Clockworkmod you need the STOCK recovery, which you can flash in ODIN. If you flasha stock rom in odin you will lose root yes. The stock ROM and CWM are totally different things by the way, your recovery is a different OS and has no bearing on the ROM, Samsung bundle the stock recovery with the ROM pacakage and it is flashed by ODIN as part of the stock installation.

Comment: So, I can flash any custom ROMs via Clockworkmod but Stock Roms can only be flashed via ODIN. Correct?

Comment: That's it yeah.