# Samsung Galaxy S4 verizon stuck in bootloop

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, linux, cache, dalvik

This is my device info:

- What forums refer to my phone as: JFLTEVZW
- Name that comes on box: Samsung Galaxy S4 Verizon SCH-I545
- Carrier: Verizon
- Unlocked: Yes
- Root: When my phone was working, Yes

I used safestrap to install hyperdrive ROM for my phone, and now it is in bootloop. I cleared my cache partition, and did a factory reset. I need to wipe DALVIK cache from my laptop because Clockwork mod and twrp does not install. is there any way to do that on linux... if there isn't is there another method. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way with a Sumsung device to fix a "soft-brick" is to use [ODIN](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool) and flash the stock firmware. You may be able to find stock firmware that is already rooted if you want that.

You can look at "[Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)".

[More information](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/what-is-the-basic-functionality-behind-the-odin-buttons-checkboxes) on what all the checkboxes mean in the ODIN tool.

Since you are on linux, you cannot run ODIN as it is a Windows only tool. However, you can run [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/), which is an open source version of ODIN that a group of developers have created. Heimdall uses the same protocols as ODIN, as it is basically a reverse engineered version of ODIN that is designed to be supported by the community and run on multiple platforms.