# How can I get my soft-bricked Note 3 to work back

Tags: unbricking

I was messing around with my Note 3's build.prop file to play a game which was created for tablets only.
After I was done with editing I just pasted back my backup build.prop file from sd card and restarted the device. Now all I see is a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9005 Screen and then everyrthing is black. 
I tried to install CWM via odin but CWM wont boot either.
I know I can flash a new ROM with Odin but i don't want to lose my files, any way that i can fix my build.prop back? Or recover my files?
Thanks

Comment: CWM is a custom recovery and has nothing to do with your current version of Android. If you just flash your actual firmware with Odin then it shouldn't wipe your `/data` partition and you keep all your data. Because you actually have CWM installed I suggest doing a Nandroid backup (full backup) of your phone before flashing and/or editing the `build.prop` file again.

Comment: Did you change permissions when putting __`build.prop`__ back into the system.

Answer (score -1):

Flash your stock rom with odin, you will not loose the files on the internal storage

Comment: Please include further details so as to anybody else with minimal knowledge would be able to follow along.

Comment: If you need information on how to use ODIN, you can look at [what is the ODIN tool](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool) and [What are the basic function of the checkboxs and buttons in ODIN](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/what-is-the-basic-functionality-behind-the-odin-buttons-checkboxes).

Comment: http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/05/89/63496881366755/0/root-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-and-flash-stock-roms-using-odin-for-windows.w654.jpg) then click pda, select the firmware that you have choosen and press start. It's easier to do than to explain.

Comment: Or follow this http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-install-restore-stock-firmware-on-samsung-galaxy-note-3-all-models/ the model is also written behind the battery and you don't need to enable usb debugging