# Downgrade Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 from KitKat to Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, downgrade, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I was using Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 for 6 months and was running on Jelly Bean. After upgrading to KitKat, it is too slow to operate.

Is there any way to downgrade my cell without rooting the phone?

Comment: Well, I guess yes there's a trick available to do that why don't you try having a look over the thread [Downgrade KitKat 4.4.2 to Jelly Bean 4.1.2](http://www.sammobile.com/forum/showthread.php?t=22975) over sammobile forum ! See if this help you.

Comment: have you tried it? or any knowledge who already have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to downgrade is to use [ODIN](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool) (or the open source alternative, [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/)). This describes the [basic functionality of the buttons and checkboxes in ODIN](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/what-is-the-basic-functionality-behind-the-odin-buttons-checkboxes/).

You need to [find the stock version of the firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) for your device. In your case, the you will want to find the JellyBean 4.1.2 version.

- Put the phone in Download Mode.

  1. Turn off your phone. Wait a few seconds and then proceed to the next step.
  2. Hold volume down, home and power buttons at the same time.
  3. Keep holding these buttons until the Samsung Logo appears on the display.
  4. Release once you see the Samsung Logo.
  5. Next press volume up key once in order to enter download mode.
- Open ODIN on your PC. Once ODIN is open, you can connect the device via USB. You may need to disconnect from and reconnect it to the computer after this for Odin to see it.
- Set the files that you found that contain the stock firmware. This will be at a minimum, a `.tar` file and may have some others to include like a `.pit` file.
- Once you have that configured, and ODIN sees your device, and you follow any other instructions that you may find where you find the stock firmware, you are now ready to **start** ODIN.

*Disclaimer: Downgrading may solve your problem, for now. You may just get the same update after you downgrade because your device will indicate that you have an outdated version of Android.*

---

ODIN is a great tool. It was one of my favorite tools when I had samsung devices. I wish all manufacturers had a tool like this. I have fixed many devices that I soft bricked with ODIN and in far less time than any other manufacturer.

The best tip I can give when flashing (with ODIN or any method), get information from multiple sources. Read them a couple times, then follow those instructions while you are performing the steps.