# How to use ODIN with more than a dozen of mbn, bin, img, ext4 files?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, bootloader, odin

I'd like to flash my SM-T813 because it's in a boot loop. I downloaded supposedly the latest firmware. I think it was a tar.md5 file, I peek into this tar file and it's a whole bunch of files:

[image]

ODIN has these slots: BL, AP, CP, CSC, USERDATA. I possibly want to lash the bootloader as well. How do I continue from here, which file is which? I see what are the slots here [What do the terms "BL", "AP", "CP", and "CSC" mean in Odin?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176515/what-do-the-terms-bl-ap-cp-and-csc-mean-in-odin), but not sure which files is which. I guess .mbn means some boot record (?). System.img is the largest, but the other img files are probably important too (actually probably most files).

Comment: Putin works with tar.md5 files

Comment: @alecxs thanks. My main machine is Linux, I can only put the tablet into download mode and I was not able to get Putin recognize it. I'll try it again. I also double check that this was a tar.md5. Any software takes tar? I tried Kies as well but SM-T813 cannot be factory resetted by it.

Comment: i meant ODIN will flash tar.md5 (through AP slot) Sorry, was written from mobile.. what's Putin? :D

Comment: @alecxs I was thinking about Heimdall https://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/

Comment: once heimdall works you can use JOdin its a frontend in Odin style https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2598203

Comment: @alecxs Heimdall vs Putin: both are powerful figures - one is in the Nordic mythology and Marvel universes, the other is as boss of Russia. I only tried Heimdall a month ago, but I don't know how I let Putin go - they don't even sound the same :D

Comment: i can far remember putin is a canadian culinary (fries + cheese)? some couchsurfers from quebec told me ;)