# Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1 on Galaxy Nexus showing droid

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, bootloader

I've been testing the Galaxy Nexus with JB 4.1.1 and this is what happened yesterday. Has anyone seen this screen?

[image]

Comment: Actually just found out it is a diagnostic tool called Fastboot. Any idea on how I activated this?

Comment: probably pressed the volume rocker along with the power button

Answer (score 10):

That screen means your device is in "download" mode, which allows it to be reflashed using Samsung's [Odin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool) utility (or the open source alternative [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/)). It's accessed by holding the volume down button when powering on your Galaxy Nexus.

Also, to clear up some confusion, this is **not** Fastboot mode - that is different. You access fastboot mode by holding down both volume up and volume down while powering on your device, and it also gives you access to a bootloader menu which you can scroll through using the volume rocker. The image on the screen is also different, and your device will not respond to fastboot commands in Odin mode. This is what the fastboot screen looks like - as I noted, you can see that the most obvious difference is that the background image is not the same:

[image: Bootloader screen]