# Unable to upgrade firmware from Samsung GT-I9000

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s, device-firmware

When I try to upgrade the firmware of a Samsung Galaxy S using Samsung Kies, it tells me "initialization not supported". Therefore I'm stuck with the original firmware.

Here's the details:

phone: Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000
android version: v2.2
No SD card installed

Samsung Kies: v2.3

Anyone can give a clue on how to solve this?

Many thanks beforehand.

Comment: Have you looked into upgrading the firmware using [Odin](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/what-is-the-odin-tool)?  A factory reset might help your Kies problem as well.  Both options would wipe your data so backup if necessary.

Comment: I can only recommend cyanogen-mod stable on the Galaxy S. It's unlikely that Samsung will release any other update then Android 2.3 and CM runs very stable on my SGS plus all the Samsung bloatware is removed.

Comment: Thanks. I did think about using a 3rd party firmware, but the phone is not mine and I'd rather not go that way. In any case, what I find strange is the error message, doesn't necessarily mean that there are no firmware updates available and offers no clues about to solve it :(