# How to revert Samsung Galaxy Mini S5570 to stock Gingerbread?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, downgrade, samsung-galaxy-mini

Here's the situation: I got this Samsung Galaxy Mini as a gift - my first smartphone - but with this obscured operating system called [[DEV][WIP][ROM][UNOFFICIAL] Android 4.2.2 CM10.1 - Nightly 20130310](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2060605). It doesn't do even some basic things, not the best way to be introduced to smartphones, right? But what can I do?

So as my first interaction with smartphones now supposed to hack a usable operating system on it as well. Let's do it. My obvious choice was to go with the latest official CyanogenMod for the system: you can read my efforts into that here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42088/adb-push-doesnt-push-myrom-zip-sdcard-though-it-says-it-copied-the-file-sams (So far no answers yet.)

My guess at this point is things could work out better if I could first revert the phone back to the official ROM. My first try was to plug it into Samsung's KIES software - but obviously it doesn't recognize the now totally hacked phone. The XDA Forum is way too overwhelming for me to go for this - as my first venture into smartphones -, could you point me to a no-nonsense, step-by-step guide how can I revert back the phone to official Gingerbread from here?

Comment: The reason ADB push (despite it copied it) is you **need** a custom recovery to flash that `MyROM.zip`. The only think I can think of is using Odin and flash a original ROM from [here](http://samfirmware.com)

Comment: @t0mm13b: Sorry. Chinese to me.

Comment: Kantonese or Mandarin? Helping you to translate, checkout e.g. [What is the ODIN tool?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18475/16575)