# Odin projects and versions

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, odin

Trying to flash my old `Samsung Galaxy Mini S5570`. For this purpose I need to use some kind of software - `Odin`. I found several versions of `odin` project.
[image]

[image]

Which one is real one and where is the right place I can download newest **Odin** verison?

Comment: As you've already tagged your question `odin`, did you check our [odin tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info)? It mentions an XDA link as download source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Odin is believed to be a *leaked* Samsung internal tool as you can see from [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(firmware_flashing_software)) . That's the reason you will not find a definitive,*official* website for downloading
- [What is the ODIN tool?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/18476) is a related answer and the point worth bearing in mind while choosing the right version is

> (....) you probably want to ensure someone else has tried it and succeeded

Now, coming to your question

> Which one is real one and where is the right place I can download newest **Odin** verison?

- IMO, having been a past Samsung user, the best place to search right version for your device is XDA forums. Above answer cites a thread for a particular device.  [LATEST ODIN v3.09 & ODIN 1.85 & ALLODIN MULTI DOWNLOADER VERSIONS
  ROM Flashing Tools for ALL Samsung smartphones](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/themes-apps/27-08-2013-odin-3-09-odin-1-85-versions-t2189539) lists out various versions of Odin /  download links and compatibility with various devices, with the disclaimer that *these ... might not be 100% accurate*. Per this your device needs **ODIN Multi Downloader v4.42**. Another source  [What Odin Version You Need For Your Phone](http://updato.com/how-to/what-odin-version-you-need-for-your-phone) *corroborates*
- To start with, that would be the choice and this being an old device, there aren't many references available from a cursory Google search. You may like to do a deeper search
- Another point to note is that tutorials on web showing how to use Odin , need to be correlated with version of Odin depicted and the one you are using, since *buttons* on tool changed. [Here](http://droidangel.blogspot.in/2011/05/procedure-how-to-flash-updateupgrade.html?m=1) is one such guide ( I don't recall which Odin I used last so can't vouch for guide correctness). You may like to Google for more
- Whichever guide you choose to follow, follow instructions *explicitly* and don't *assume*. This caution is to ensure that you don't end up bricking your device. All the best

Comment: By the way, once you've grabbed an Odin, you can have it updated via a mysterious Korean server (property of Samsung), via FTP.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman. Thanks. I am aware of it but never used it. Here the OP appears to have picked up a later version, which may not support his device (no *guaranteed backward compatibility* AFAIK) thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

I have heard many times that the Version 4 of ODIN, was mainly used for Tablets in house. I've ALWAYS used some Version of 3 for all my flashing. And I've almost exclusively used Samsung Devices since the Captivate. I've Never used Version 4 of ODIN for my mobile phones. Never used it period actually.

As far as backwards compatibility though, I have a Galaxy S7 Edge and can flash files to it using Odin 3.10.7, when the current version is now 3.13.2.

From what I know at this moment, the change from Odin 1.87 to 3.07 to 3.10.x to 3.12.x to 3.13.x, is because of certain compression used in the filesystem images contained on some different devices. Or in the case of v1.87 to 3.07 was because we moved from RFS to EXT4 from what I remember.

I am not sure what changed from 3.07 to 3.10.x to 3.12.x yet. I've been looking into this for like 3 days now. I do know that the change to 3.13.x was to support the LZ4 compression used in the firmware images for the Galaxy/Note S8 and S9.

There are also many different versions of ODIN available now besides the leaked samsung versions. We now also have these:

1.) Jesters Modded ODIN (Based on 3.12.x I believe, and used for AT&T Branded devices. I haven't gotten an answer as to why yet.)

2.) Prince Comsy's ODIN (Based on 3.12, modified to bypass SHA1 checksum): I'm not sure why bypassing this checksum matters actually. I've read that it is used for cross carrier flashing. But it was originally made for flashing firmware to the G930/5 A (AT&T Galaxy S7/Edge).

3.) Patched ODIN 3.13.1 (ODIN BR? Based on 3.13.1 lol, but modified to bypass the SHA256 Checksum) Again, I'm not even sure why that checksum needs bypassed or even what bypassing those checksums does for flashing.

---

What I'd honestly LOVE to know, is how the binary executables were so specifically modified, and how it was found to even be viable in the first place.

Samsung's Download mode is a thing of mystery to most, because those that do know, won't talk about it for some reason. Ever since the Galaxy S6 was released, information on the devices has been SO hush-hush it's ridiculous. Once Chaine Fire quit working on most Samsung devices, most developers left as well. And that left a Void.

It also left in its wake, so many possible root methods Chainfire never even tried. Samsung Android IS NOT GOOGLE ANDROID. The same things do not apply, as we saw with the Xposed Framework. The Android Runtime (ART) needed modified to get Xposed to work on Samsung initially. Samsung changed a lot. So a different method is needed...

Comment: Have you considered [Heimdall](https://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) instead of Odin? This sounds more like ranting about the status quo than a useful answer.